# Google Sheets x axis date and y axis multiple columns from data in one column in the source data

Tags: google-sheets, charts

I am trying to create a chart in Google Sheets that lists aggregated dates on the x axis and parts and related quantities on the y axis. The issue I am having is that the part source data is in one column. I need to know how I can get the y axis to display a column for each of the parts contained in the source column. I have attached an image that shows what I want vs what I am getting. The chart sums all parts together on a given date as opposed to breaking them down by part on a given date. How can I get the sheet to create an individual column for each part on a given date? Yellow is Part A and Red is Part B.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

1. Make a Pivot Table in `Data->Pivot Table` to reorganize the table. Add `Date` to Rows field and `Part` to Columns field. Add `Quantity` to Values field.
2. Create a column chart using the generated Pivot Table.

**Sample Sheet:**

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you for your help!

Comment: Very much appreciated! :)